# ADF - Data Flow Source Option - 'Column to store file name' - How do I use this?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In an ADF Data Flow I have set up a Source and in the Source Options tab I have set the value in the 'Column to store file name' as 'myFileName'.

However, I don't see this new 'myFileName' in the column list for any transforms later in the flow.

How do I access this column value?

[image: source options]

Answer (score 1):

It should absolutely be there:

[image]

In the subsequent Derived Column, under Inspect:

[image]